# Query a Map containing an ID saved in Cloud Firestore with Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How to get a Map stored in Cloud Firestore with Dart/Flutter ?
I tried this but it only works with Array :

```
Firestore.instance
            .collection('posts')
            .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
            .where("userlist", arrayContains: userId)
            .snapshots(),
```

here is the map stored in firebase

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense for `userlist` to be an array here.  Firestore doesn't let you query for values of maps inside an array.  Just store it as a map.  If `userlist` was just a map of uid/value pairs, you could query it like this using dot notation:

```
Firestore.instance
        .collection('posts')
        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
        .where('userlist.' + userId, isEqualTo: true)
        .snapshots(),
```

Comment: Thank you ! Effectively it was a map stored in a list. It solved the problem on firebase side. However with this code on flutter side, I get the snapshot but it's empty. I have the exact same syntax than you and userId is the same as first key value. Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: If you have a new situation with a different problem, you should post that as a new quesiton.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried both Doug Stevenson's and Dan James's answers and was getting empty array as a result.

I've finally received the correct result by using the where clause with not equal to ''

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to Doug Stevenson's answer, I had to use the key `isGreaterThan: ''` in order to not get an empty array.

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('posts')
    .where('userlist.' + userId, isGreaterThan: '')
    .snapshots(),
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend your way of data model. Because of some limitations as below:

1. You can only have 20000 fields in a firestore document (including array fields).
2. You can't assign security rules to each field. Security Rules is a thing that you have to think of.
3. You can't query them.

So, better I would recommend you to use documents for each user.